# Split audio stream with sox and process chunks with script

Tags: split, sox

I use sox for splitting audio stream like this

```
stream | sox -t raw -r 16k -e signed -b 16 -c 1 - ./chunks/output.wav  silence 1 0.3 0.1% 1 0.3 0.1% trim 0 55 : newfile : restart
```

Now sox write chunks to chunks folder. Can I pipe them to script for processing without writing to disk?

Something like this

```
stream | sox | node script.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Unix pipes always pass on byte streams. However, the whole point of your splitting is that you get multiple byte streams, and it's impossible to pass multiple byte streams through a single pipe (unless you concatenate them again into a single byte stream, which defeats the purpose of splitting them).

You can call your script on each of the chunk files in the chunk folder using the usual `bash` for-loop, or `parallel`, or whatever you like.

You could also use a program that allows you to call an external program on each split chunk. AFAIK `sox` can't do that, but there may be other audio splitting programs that can.